# Windows SSL NodeJS PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, certificate, pem

I have a free ssl cert from GeoTrust for 1 month. I copied the cert text into notepad and saved it as an ansi encoded file with a pem extension.

I also saved the private key into another file as ansi with a pem extension.

When I point Nodejs to these files it gives the error: PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start

Here's the node code:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('geocrt.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('geokey.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

My cert begins with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and ends with -----END CERTIFICATE-----

My key begins with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and ends with -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

This is on Windows. I have no idea what's going on. Please help!

UPDATE: I think I've gotten a little further. I notice I had my cert and key options reversed on accident (face palm), but now when I launch my node app it just hangs. I never get the console to log that the server has started, just a blank line that I eventually have to break out of. Please help!

UPDATE 2: cURL returns this error when I run app.js:

> curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to localhost:443